# scala Option type difference

Tags: scala, scala-option

What is the difference between passing two arguments vs passing one argument?

```
val option1 = Option(String,String)
and
val option2 = Option(String)
```

Comment: Oh c'mon. Just run it in the REPL and observe the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write something like `Option(1, 2)`, the compiler first desugars this to `Option.apply(1, 2)`, and then when it sees that the `Option` companion object doesn't have an `apply` method that takes two arguments, it automatically converts the arguments into a tuple:

```
scala> Option(1, 2)
res0: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,2))
```

It would do something similar for `Option(1, 2, 3)`, `Option(1, 2, 3, 4)`, etc.

This is known as auto-tupling and only works for methods with a single argument. For example, the following won't compile:

```
scala> def foo[T](t: T, u: T): T = t
foo: [T](t: T, u: T)T

scala> foo(1, 2, 3)
<console>:13: error: too many arguments for method foo: (t: T, u: T)T
       foo(1, 2, 3)
          ^
```

This "feature" is provided for syntactic convenience, and it brings Scala a little closer (at least in a superficial way) to other functional languages where tuples and function argument lists are more unified. Lots of people hate auto-tupling, though, because these things aren't actually unified in Scala, and pretending they are can lead to confusing code and annoying error messages. If you're one of these people (I am), you can turn on the `-Ywarn-adapted-args` compiler flag, which gives you warnings when the compiler tries to do this:

```
scala> Option(1, 2)
<console>:12: warning: Adapting argument list by creating a 2-tuple: this may not be what you want.
        signature: Option.apply[A](x: A): Option[A]
  given arguments: 1, 2
 after adaptation: Option((1, 2): (Int, Int))
       Option(1, 2)
             ^
res0: Option[(Int, Int)] = Some((1,2))
```

This is a matter of taste, though.

Comment: How come Jörg got a compile error in the other answer? Does auto-tupling not work reliably (can be turned off, or not available in the REPL or something)?

Comment: @Thilo I don't know what code he was actually trying to compile. As far as I know it's not possible to turn auto-tupling _off_, although `-Ywarn-adapted-args` plus fatal errors gets you something similar.

Comment: @TravisBrown I have  RDD[(Int, (Option[String], Option[(Option[String], Option[String])]))]. I can have case(id:Int,option1,optionTuple) and use optionTupel._1 and optionTuple._2 to access the values. Can I have all the options in case like case(id:Int,(option1,optionTupel(tuple1,tuple2)))

Comment: @GG I'm not sure I understand but that sounds like it should be a new question of its own.

Comment: @Thilo: because the OP's code is `Option(String, String)`, whereas Travis's code is `Option(1, 2)`. `1` and `2` *are* values, they are instances of the `scala.Int` class. `String` is *not* a value, it is a *type*. Travis's answer answers a very different question than the OP is asking.

Comment: I read the question as contrasting `Option(x, y)` and `Option(x)` for some arbitrary strings or whatever, not about the `String` part specifically, which is a non-starter even for the `Option(String)` case. Maybe the OP can clarify the intent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload of [`Option.apply`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option$.html#apply[A](x:A):Option[A]) with two arguments, so the simple difference between the two is that the first one gives an error related to the number of arguments:

```
error: too many arguments (2) for method apply: (x: A)Option[A] in object Option
```

Whereas the second one gives an error because `String` is a type, not a value, and you are trying to pass a type as an argument, which is impossible:

```
error: object java.lang.String is not a value
```

Comment: I'm not what the OP is asking but I feel like he is asking `Option("Jam Baxter", "Dirty Dike")` vs `Option("Fliptrix")`

Comment: Also should not the error be `object java.lang.String is not a value` for both case? Because `too many arguments for apply` does not make any sense as it takes if you provide real values. eg `Option("Jam Baxter", "Dirty Dike")`

Comment: I cut and pasted the code *directly* from the OP's question, and those were the results I got (and also the results I expected, at least the second one).

Comment: My best guess is that overload resolution doesn't even look at the arguments if it cannot even find an overload with the right arity. It makes sense, really: why would you want to perform name resolution (which in the Scala type system is Turing-complete, after all!) if you already know that there is no applicable overload anyway!

Comment: My answer is addressing the question in prose and yours is taking the example code literally—I guess both are worthwhile until the OP clarifies what they mean.