# passing non tuple to (Int,Int)=>() compiles, why?

Tags: scala

Can someone explain why the code below compiles ?

I think it should not compile.

```
object RandomExperiments extends App{
  def takeTuple(t:(Int,Int))=print (s"$t ${t._1}\n")
  takeTuple(1,3) // this should not compile !!!
  takeTuple (1,3) // this should not compile !!!
  takeTuple((1,3))
  takeTuple(((1,3)))

  def takeTwoInts(i1:Int,i2:Int)=print (s"$i1 $i2\n")

  takeTwoInts(1,2)

  // takeTwoInts((1,2)) // does not compile , this is expected

}

(1,3) 1
(1,3) 1
(1,3) 1
(1,3) 1
1 2
```

Comment: This is Scala's auto-tupling "feature". See e.g my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42730285/334519) for some discussion and an option you can enable to make this result in warnings, at least.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806982/scala-type-parameter-being-inferred-to-tuple

Comment: Thanks, interesting to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's known as auto-tupling. The compiler sees that there is no overload available for `takeTuple` that has two `Int` arguments, but recognizes that if the arguments can be converted to an `(Int, Int)` and makes the conversion. If you compile with `-Xlint:_`, you will see a warning like this:

```
scala> takeTuple(1,3)
<console>:12: warning: Adapting argument list by creating a 2-tuple: this may not be what you want.
        signature: takeTuple(t: (Int, Int)): Unit
  given arguments: 1, 3
 after adaptation: takeTuple((1, 3): (Int, Int))
       takeTuple(1,3)
                ^
```

You could use the `-Yno-adapted-args` flag (recommended) to disable this feature

Comment: Thanks for the answer !